# add onsubmit attribute to form and submit it

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have two buttons on page:

```
<div class="bottons">
        <button class="wiz_button wizard_prev_step" type="button" style="margin-top: 27px;
            display: none"><span><span>Previous</span></span></button>
        <form id="orderForm" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="Signed_Order_B64" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="email" size="50" maxlength="50" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="Language" value="rus">
        <input type="hidden" name="firstname" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="surname" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="appendix" value="">            
        <button class="wiz_button wizard_next_step disabled long" type="button" style="margin-top: 27px;">
            <span><span>Next</span></span></button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

This buttons from my custom wizard. Also, I have a click event handler for `Next` button:

```
$('.wizard_next_step').click(function () {
// load next step and other stuff
})
```

I want when user locate on the last step the post form:

```
if (currentStep === '3') {
// here I want set onsubmit function for the form  *
}
```

How can I do this?
Thanks.

PS. The solution must works in IE 7 and above.

Comment: You might to check out [this plugin](http://elclanrs.github.com/jq-idealforms/)

Answer (score 1):

Just do:

```
$('#orderForm').submit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your are using jQuery. so simply use

```
if (currentStep === '3') {
// here I want set onsubmit function for the form and submit it *
  $('#orderForm').submit();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the button is in the form, and within the attached listener `this` will reference the button, you can assign to the onsubmit property using:

```
this.form.onsubmit = someFn;
```

and submit the form using:

```
this.form.submit();
```